# How to resolve home partition tied to older Ubuntu version?

Tags: grub2, 12.04, partitioning

I reinstalled Precise, over the existing Oneiric install and assigned the partitions manually. I have 3 partitions dedicated to Ubuntu. The '/' partition I set to format. The '/boot' partition also I formatted. To retain the home partition with Precise, I assigned  it as '/home'.

Two problems have surfaced - 1. The /home partition has been identified correctly by Precise, but none of my data was carried over, despite my not formatting the partition. 2. In my grub list on boot, an extra entry now occurs -
Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) on /dev/sda9

Could you  tell me why this could have happened. And how to rectify it? I guess the data's gone, but how to resolve the partition still being linked with Oneiric.

Thanks!

Outputs for

1. sudo blkid

   ```
   /dev/sda7: UUID="a9c7641a-7579-42a6-90c1-330cffc06e42" TYPE="ext2" 
   /dev/sda8: UUID="ef7ace89-9cfb-4ecc-8a86-654b3f926bbe" TYPE="swap" 
   /dev/sda9: UUID="8d8b94a9-5dd7-42f9-b91e-f4d4de3aa0c8" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda10: UUID="de2f4e35-3e40-495b-bff2-091308b08cb6" TYPE="ext4"
   ```
2. sudo cat /etc/fstab

   ```
   <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
   proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
   / was on /dev/sda10 during installation
   UUID=de2f4e35-3e40-495b-bff2-091308b08cb6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   /boot was on /dev/sda7 during installation
   UUID=a9c7641a-7579-42a6-90c1-330cffc06e42 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
   /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
   UUID=8d8b94a9-5dd7-42f9-b91e-f4d4de3aa0c8 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
   swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
   UUID=ef7ace89-9cfb-4ecc-8a86-654b3f926bbe none            swap    sw              0       0
   ```
3. sudo update-grub

   ```
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
   Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
   Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
   Found Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) on /dev/sda9
   ```

Comment: Correct me if that's wrong, but upgrading usually doesn't involve manually assigning or formatting partitions. What you describe sounds a lot like a reinstall.

Comment: @mikewhatever - Yes, it isn't the actual upgrade option. I meant that I just retained the home partition and yes, I reinstalled the OS.

Comment: Right, thanks for clarifying. To use another partition as /home, you'll need to edit /etc/fstab, and redirect it to the appropriate partition. If you need help with that, please add the outputs of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` to the original question.

Comment: @mikewhatever - Thanks for the help! I have added the outputs suggested by you in the question. I apologise for not phrasing my question properly. I have clarified it better now. I think Precise has identified the /home partition correctly, but none of my data from Oneiric has been carried over and in grub the partition is still shown as Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

According to your `fstab`, /dev/sda9 is the /home partition for the new installation. On the other hand, the Ubuntu 11.10 entry from the same partition suggests the presence of boot files there, which implies, the it has been a system (or a boot) partition before. I suspect that something like `ls /home/` will reveal the old installation of 11.10 on /dev/sda9.

How that happened is not very clear. I can only guess that the / and /home partitions has been misidentified at the time of installation, the old / has been assigned to /home, and not formatted, whereas the old /home may have been assigned to /, and formatted. You might take a look at the old fstab on /dev/sda9, to gather more info.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood your explanation as to what might have happened. I think I will just remove the irrelevant entries from the grub menu list manually, as I am uncertain of any other method and do a fresh install when 12.10 comes around.